# How to add a toggle inside a title of the barchart js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have this barchart created in the ChartJS last version.
I want to add a toggle button inside the barchart title, as shown in this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KMyB.png

This is my barchart code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myBarChart");
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [{
            label: "Valor",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
            borderColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
            data: [],
        }],
    },
    options: {
        plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                anchor: 'end',
                align: 'top',
                formatter: function (value, context) {
                    if (value != 0) {
                        return new Date(value * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
                    } else {
                        value = " "
                        return value;
                    }
                },
                font: {
                    weight: 'bold'
                }
            }
        },
        responsive: true,
        tooltips: {
            /*  intersect: false, */
            callbacks: {
                title: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                    return data['labels'][tooltipItem[0]['index']];
                },
                label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                    return new Date(parseInt(data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem[
                        'index']]) * 1000).toISOString().substr(11,
                        8);
                },
            },
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                time: {
                    unit: 'month'
                },
                gridLines: {
                    display: false
                },
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    min: 0,
                    suggestedMax: 36000,
                    stepSize: 3600,
                    beginAtZero: true,
                },
            }],
        },
    }
});
```

Is it something possible to do?
If someone know how to do this in the last version of the chartjs, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the core plugin API to write a custom plugin that does it. The better and easyer option to to not use the title of chart.js and put a div above your chart and put your title and the toggle in that div with HTML